# Unable to download file from google drive

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-plugins, gargle

I am currently trying to run R scripts from Jenkins via the following plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/r/) all on an AWS EC2 instance

The problem now is that I can't authenticate myself in a non-interactive way as indicated by the gargle library documentation.

The gargle cache is well filled (here is the sitrep)

```
ℹ Taking cache location from the `"gargle_oauth_cache"` option.
1 token found in this gargle OAuth cache:
'~/.cache/gargle'

email            app             scopes   hash...   
________________ _______________ ________ __________
secret@secret.fr tidyverse-erato ...drive 928dfaa...
```

but the drive_auth method always returns the same error:

```
Error in `drive_auth()`:
! Can't get Google credentials
ℹ Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider:
• `drive_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials
• Call `drive_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics
ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
ℹ <https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html>
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─googledrive::drive_auth(...)
 2.   └─googledrive:::drive_abort(...)
 3.     └─cli::cli_abort(message = message, ..., .envir = .envir)
 4.       └─rlang::abort(...)
Execution halted
```

And so I can't download a remote file placed on my drive:

```
drive_download(as_id("id"), path = "~/sku.csv", overwrite = TRUE)
sku <- read_csv2("~/sku.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "CP1252"),
                 col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, guess_max = 20000)
print(sku)
```

my code:

```
#### R Library ####
library(utils)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(gargle)
library(googledrive)
library(readr)
library(DBI)
library(httr)
library(cronR)
library(RPostgreSQL) # Connect PostgreSQL db
options(encoding = "CP1252")
Sys.setenv(TZ="CET")
default_locale()

## Settings for Google Drive connexion
options(gargle_verbosity = "debug")
options(gargle_oauth_cache = "~/.cache/gargle")
options(httr_oob_default = TRUE)
gargle_oauth_sitrep()
print(gargle_verbosity())
print(sessionInfo())

drive_auth(email = "secret@secret.com",
          scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
          use_oob = TRUE,
          cache = "~/.cache/gargle") # mettre cache = FALSE si on souhaite generer un nouveau token
print(drive_user())
# From Drive
#### From cloud
### Products & co.
## Import
# Sku
drive_download(as_id(id), path = "~/sku.csv", overwrite = TRUE)
sku <- read_csv2("~/sku.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "CP1252"),
                 #col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, guess_max = 20000)
print(sku)
# Permet de reinitialiser les recuperations d'hyperlien sur GOOGLE # 
# suite a des updates pour eviter des erreurs #
```

I also tried to connect to the GUI of my instance in order to connect interactively to fill the cache for the first time and used the same token, but also without success.

I edit this post :

I also precise that I run the same script on Rstudio & Jenkins which are installed on the same instance AWS ec2. I got my token thanks to an authentification page on browser with "drive_auth" on Rstudio.

After "drive_auth()" function written as above, I have :

On Jenkins :

```
trying `token_fetch()`
trying `credentials_byo_oauth()`
Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
inherits(token, "Token2.0") is not TRUE
trying `credentials_service_account()`
Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
trying `credentials_external_account()`
adding "userinfo.email" scope
Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
trying `credentials_app_default()`
trying `credentials_gce()`
trying `credentials_user_oauth2()`
attempt to access internal gargle data from: gargle
Gargle2.0 initialize
adding "userinfo.email" scope
loading token from the cache
no matching token in the cache
initiating new token`
```

and on Rstudio :

```
trying `token_fetch()`
    trying `credentials_byo_oauth()`
    Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
    inherits(token, "Token2.0") is not TRUE
    trying `credentials_service_account()`
    Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
    Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
    trying `credentials_external_account()`
    adding "userinfo.email" scope
    Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
    Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
    trying `credentials_app_default()`
    trying `credentials_gce()`
    trying `credentials_user_oauth2()`
    attempt to access internal gargle data from: gargle
    Gargle2.0 initialize
    adding "userinfo.email" scope
    loading token from the cache
    matching token found in the cache
```

Even if Jenkins see the token in the same cache as Rstudio, it doesn't work but it working well on Rstudio. Jenkins wants a new token even if the token is located.

EDIT:
I now try to set up the authentification via service account token that i got from the GCP console, i followed these steps (https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html#service-account-token)

And now I got this error:

```
trying `token_fetch()`
trying `credentials_byo_oauth()`
Error caught by `token_fetch()`:
inherits(token, "Token2.0") is not TRUE
trying `credentials_service_account()`
adding "userinfo.email" scope
service account email:
'googledrive-sheets@exemple.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
attempt to access internal gargle data from: googledrive
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `gargle::response_process()`:
! Client error: (404) Not Found
File not found: 1qUJheGEPlZrzSNlwFBdC1UilwScexlHx.
• message: File not found: 1qUJheGEPlZrzSNlwFBdC1UilwScexlHx.
• domain: global
• reason: notFound
• location: fileId
• locationType: parameter
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. └─googledrive::drive_download(...)
  2.   ├─googledrive::as_dribble(file)
  3.   └─googledrive:::as_dribble.drive_id(file)
  4.     └─googledrive::drive_get(id = x)
  5.       ├─googledrive::as_dribble(map(as_id(id), get_one_file_id))
  6.       └─purrr::map(as_id(id), get_one_file_id)
  7.         └─purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
  8.           ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
  9.           │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 10.           ├─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
 11.           └─googledrive (local) .f(.x[[i]], ...)
 12.             └─gargle::response_process(response)
 13.               └─gargle:::gargle_abort_request_failed(error_message(resp), resp)
 14.                 └─gargle:::gargle_abort(...)
 15.                   └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 16.                     └─rlang::abort(...)
Execution halted
Build step 'Execute R script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you check out the webpage mentioned in the error? https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html If you are trying to set this up with Jenkins you'll need a non-interactive login.

Comment: Yes I've already check this page and I add "use_oob = TRUE" for non-interactive session, I add the option on gargle_verbosity etc...

I installed Rstudio on the same instance as Jenkins. I was able to generate a token thanks to the tidyverse authentication page which opened in the browser. Jenkins manages to see the token in the cache but cannot retrieve it. The same script run on Rstudio works but doesn't work on Jenkins. Here is the difference between the two.

Comment: You have `options(gargle_oauth_cache = "~/.cache/gargle")` which means the path is user specific (the `~` refers to the current user's home directory). I'm guessing Jenkins is running as a different user than you are using in RStudio. Try setting that to a path that both users can access.

Comment: Jenkins and Rstudio are on the same instance AWS ec2, so they are using the same user. I precise that Jenkins can see the hidden token in the cache "~/.cache/gargle", it just cannot "read" the token cause I always have the same error "no matching token in the cache"... I'm going to be crazy, it's really weird.

Comment: You can use path.expand() on the path with the tilde to get the full path. Maybe print that out and compare. Also look at he the file on disk and see what permissions it has.

Comment: `path.expand()` returns the exact same path on jenkins and rstudio. there is no difference between both paths. I also granted higher permissions on both files and the cache folder itself without success.